# Taking the dot product of sum and difference of two unit vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I was taking the dot product $(\hat v+\hat w)\cdot(\hat v-\hat w)$ for $2$ arbitrary unit vectors $\hat v$ and $\hat w$.

$$=\sum (v_i+w_i)(v_i-w_i)\\
=\sum v_i^2-w_i^2\\
=\|\hat v\|^2-\|\hat w\|^2\\
=0$$

Then, I tried taking it the other way:

$$0=\|\hat v+\hat w\|\|\hat v-\hat w\|\cos\theta\\
=\sqrt{\sum (v_i+w_i)^2\sum (v_i-w_i)^2}\cos\theta\\
=\sqrt{\sum(v_i^2+w_i^2+2v_iw_i)\sum(v_i^2+w_i^2-2v_iw_i)}{\cos\theta}\\
=\sqrt{\left(\|\hat v\|^2+\|\hat w\|^2+2\hat v\cdot \hat w\right)\left(\|\hat v\|^2+\|\hat w\|^2-2\hat v\cdot \hat w\right)}{\cos\theta}\\
=2\sqrt{1-(\hat v\cdot\hat w)^2}\cos\theta\\
=2\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}\cos\theta\\
=\sin(2|\theta|)
$$
This implies the vectors have to be perpendicular or colinear, but I never specified that in the first place. Did I make a mistake or is there some misunderstanding?

Comment: Well, for one thing you appear to be assuming that the angle between $\vec v$ and $\vec w$ is the same as the angle between $(\vec v+\vec w)$ and $(\vec v-\vec w)$ whereas the latter two vectors are perpendicular.

Comment: @lulu Oh I understand, thank you!

Comment: Glad to help. $\quad$

Comment: Actually you proved that the two vectors are perpendicular.

Comment: @lulu do you want to post that as an answer?